# Late 70's or 80's romantic film when a guy falls for a ghost living in his house

Tags: story-identification, movie, ghost

I saw this film on tv when I was young, so I don't know any of the actors in the film. I believe the guy is a writer and he moves into this old home. Soon he discovers a woman taking a bath in his tub and he wonders how she got in.  But soon discovers that she is a ghost.

She visits him many nights. One night a kitten wonders into his home and he starts taking care of it. Later in the week he discovers that it drowned in the bathtub. He believes the ghost killed it to have companionship.

The two start to fall in love and she convinces him to kill himself in the lake behind the house to stay with her in the afterlife.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this ***[The Forgotten One](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099601/?ref_=kw_li_tt)*** (1989)...?

> A recently widowed writer moves into a Victorian house that is supposedly haunted. Although he is attracted to his pretty next-door neighbor, he finds himself being seduced by the spirit of a woman who had been murdered in his house 100 years previously.

- It about the right age and the synopsis matches the premise you described.
- At around the 45:05 mark in the video below, there's a scene where the ghost is taking a bath in the protagonist's house, but when he goes to the bathroom to investigate, there's no one there.
- At around the 47:50 mark, the man is playing a piano when he notices that a stray kitten has wandered in. Later, at around the 1:02:45 mark, he finds the kitten drowned in his bathtub.

Comment: I love you soooooooooo much!!!!!!! I have been looking for this movie forever! THANK YOU! THANK YOU! THANK YOU